# Convert data from URL into Image in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, json, image, nsdata, nsurl

Here I'm working for static URL.

My Code :

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://cns.bu.edu/~lgrady/diagonal_line_nobreak_seg.jpg"];

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:myData];
```

So, I can see image in ImageView.

But, While passing internal web-service URL.

And I'm getting data for Image in bytes from url instead of Image like below:

```
{"AppBanner":"data:image\/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg.....VORK5CYII="}
```

But with help of above code, I can't convert this data into Image.

So how can I convert this data into image ?

Any Solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [NSData-Base64](https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64/) to convert base64 into NSData and then into UIImage

```
NSString  *strBase64 = [yourResposeDict objectForKey:@"AppBanner"];
//decode strBase64 using NSData-Base64 library
```